# Strange about subprocess.call in Python

Tags: python

Because the subprocess.call invoke cmd .exe flash off, just return value '1', which indicates a run error. I only screenshot to explain.

Under win cmd, it runs well. Why does it break in subprocess.call?

```
Year:    979
Year:    980
Year:    981
Year:    982
Year:    983
Year:    984
Year:    985
Year:    986
Year:    987
Year:    988
Year:    989
SPINUP: residual trend  = -0.000069
SPINUP: number of years = 990
H:\calibration\bgcclimb>pointbgc.exe .\ini\spinup\t59_13_79_29_11_80_8.ini
```

Use subproceess.call in Python: return value '1' ,not '0'

```
 subprocess.call([r'H:\calibration\bgcclimb\pointbgc.exe',r'.\ini\spinup\t59_13_79_29_11_80_8.ini'])
Out[7]: 1
```

Use subprocess.Popen check stderr:

```
process = subprocess.Popen([r'H:\calibration\bgcclimb\pointbgc.exe',r'.\ini\spinup\t59_13_79_29_11_80_8.ini'], shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()
errcode = process.returncode

err
 Out[3]: b"Can't open .\\ini\\spinup\\t59_13_79_29_11_80_8.ini for ascii read ... Exiting\r\nError opening init file, pointbgc.c\r\n"
```

Comment: Capture the stdout and stderr or the call and it will probably tell you what is wrong.

Comment: stderr hint: `b"Can't open .\\ini\\spinup\\t59_13_79_29_11_80_8.ini for ascii read ... Exiting\r\nError opening init file, pointbgc.c\r\n"` @ers81239

Comment: Please don't post *pictures* of text.  Just post the text itself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the relative path that you are using.  Specify the full the path to the .ini file.

I'm not an expert on this, but it something like this:  When you call subprocess.call, the OS is running that in a new environment.  It isn't even really a full shell unless you pass shell=True.  So, in the new environment, the current working directory is either different or unset, so referring to a relative path isn't working.